# Can you accept the alternative hypothesis is the Wilcoxon rank sign test says to retain the null hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-signed-rank

All the tests that were carried out prior to WRS test shows to reject null hypothesis, but WRS test is saying to retain the null hypothesis.
However, rejecting the null hypothesis makes more sence. Is it right if i go against the WRS test and reject null hypothesis?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you performing multiple tests?